# Is there a smart way to modify an array within an object by using JavaScript's destructuring approach?

Tags: javascript

The following example demonstrates what I would like to achieve:

```
const data_template = {
  key: 1,
  data_object: {
    data1: 1,
    data2: 2,
    data3: 3
  },
  data_array: [
    { key: 1, data1: 1 },
    { key: 2, data1: 2 },
    { key: 3, data1: 3 }
  ]
}

let data = [];

data.push({ ...data_template, key: 1 });
data.push({ ...data_template, key: 2 });

console.log(data);
```

By using destructuring I can easily modify my "template object" (`data_template`) while adding instances of it to my "data array". The result of the code above is:

```
[
  {
    key: 1,
    data_object: { data1: 1, data2: 2, data3: 3 },
    data_array: [ [Object], [Object], [Object] ]
  },
  {
    key: 2,
    data_object: { data1: 1, data2: 2, data3: 3 },
    data_array: [ [Object], [Object], [Object] ]
  }
]
```

As you can see, there are 2 objects in my array (`data`), each with a unique key (1 and 2, respectively).

Now my question: How can I modify the keys within `data_array`, which is an array within my "data template"? Is there a smart way to do this by destructuring as well?

Comment: Depends on your definition of "smart"....

Comment: Note that spreading an object containing other objects does not deference the nested objects. In your example, each `data_object` value is the same object, and changing any one of them will change the others as well. The same goes for each `data_array`. If this isn't the behavior you want, you'd be better off creating a function/class to produce the kind of template object you want.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what you're trying to do.

If you simply want to clone the array with extra elements:

```js
data.push({
    ...data_template,
    key: 1,
    data_array: [
        ...data_template.data_array,
        { key: 4, data1: 4},
    ],
});
```

If you want to e.g. add a new field to all the objects inside `data_array`:

```js
const data_template = {
    key: 1,
    data_object: { data1: 1, data2: 2, data3: 3 },
    data_array: [ { key: 1, data1: 1 }, { key: 2, data1: 2 }, { key: 3, data1: 3 }]
}

console.log({
    ...data_template,
    key: 1,
    data_array: data_template.data_array.map(d => ({ ...d, newField: 123 })),
});
```

*which you could also use to overwrite the `key` field*

Otherwise I can't immediately think of any other destructuring "tricks" you could use.

Answer (score 0):

**The short answer**

No, you cant.

JavaScript destructuring only allows you to override root level keys of an object, which replaces their value.

(You also usually wouldn't do this, to keep cognitive complexity low.)

**The long answer**

There are actually better ways to do this.

Usually when creating a new object by spreading becomes more complex, you'd simply create a function for each level of nesting, and give it a better name than I did, that correlates to your domain.

This is exactly what functions are made for; to split pieces of code to reduce complexity.

**Simple example**

```js
function createDataEntry(key, data) {
  return { key, data }
}

function createRecord(key, data) {
  return {
    key,
    dataObject: {
      data,
    },
    dataArray: [
      createDataEntry(key, data),
      // or simply:
      // { key, data },
    ]
  }
}

let data = [];

data.push(createRecord(1, 'foo'));
data.push(createRecord(2, 'bar'));

console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
```

produces

```json
[
  {
    "key": 1,
    "dataObject": {
      "data": "foo"
    },
    "dataArray": [
      {
        "key": 1,
        "data": "foo"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "key": 2,
    "dataObject": {
      "data": "bar"
    },
    "dataArray": [
      {
        "key": 2,
        "data": "bar"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

**Add + Edit example**

If you want to add or edit an entry from that data array, you'll have to do a check to see if an entry already exists.

If it already exists, update it using map.

If it does not exist, use array.push().

```js
function addOrUpdateEntry(myObject, key, data) {
  let updated = false;

  const updatedObject = {
    ...myObject,
    items: myObject.items.map(member => {
      if (member.key === key) {
        updated = true;
        return { ...member, data };
      }

      return member;
    })
  };

  if (!updated) {
    updatedObject.items.push({ key, data });
  }

  return updatedObject;
}

let data = {
  items: []
};

data = addOrUpdateEntry(data, 1, "foo");
data = addOrUpdateEntry(data, 2, "bar");
data = addOrUpdateEntry(data, 2, "baz");

console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
```

Which will output

```json
{
  "items": [
    {
      "key": 1,
      "data": "foo"
    },
    {
      "key": 2,
      "data": "baz"
    }
  ]
}
```

Note that mutating an existing object can easily make for undesired behaviour in JavaScript, hence the creation of a new object and returning that from the function.

This concept is called `immutability`.